# Package for Multidimensional Density Estimation

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, density-function, density-estimation

I may be missing something obvious, but is there a python package that can reliably do density estimation of a PDF in high dimensions (e.g. 512)? I know of scipy's `gaussian_kde` but KDE methods work poorly in high dimensions. There is a lot of literature on various ways to get high dimensional density estimation to work, but is there a good, efficient implemented method somewhere that someone knows of?

Comment: Close-voters: I believe this question is primarily about *statistics*, not *programming*, and that it should therefore stay open. See [Closing "software questions".](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5985/1352) More precisely, you need to understand the statistics to be able to meaningfully recommend an implementation.

Comment: agreed @StephanKolassa.